# Understanding NioEventLoopGroup behavior related to ephermal ports upon instantiation

Tags: netty

We noticed that once you instantiate a NioEventLoopGroup it will create 2 * *threadParameter* of established connections that are cross connected.  So if you pass in 16 as the number of threads you will get 32 connections.  We would like to better understand what these connections are used for. Just to be clear we see this far before any client connection is ever invoked.

```
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57947 localhost 57946 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57968 localhost 57969 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57969 localhost 57968 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57970 localhost 57971 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57971 localhost 57970 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57972 localhost 57973 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57973 localhost 57972 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57974 localhost 57975 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57975 localhost 57974 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57976 localhost 57977 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57977 localhost 57976 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57978 localhost 57979 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57979 localhost 57978 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57980 localhost 57981 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57981 localhost 57980 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57982 localhost 57983 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57983 localhost 57982 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57984 localhost 57985 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57985 localhost 57984 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57986 localhost 57987 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57987 localhost 57986 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57988 localhost 57989 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57989 localhost 57988 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57990 localhost 57991 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57991 localhost 57990 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57992 localhost 57993 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57993 localhost 57992 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57994 localhost 57995 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57995 localhost 57994 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57996 localhost 57997 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57997 localhost 57996 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57998 localhost 57999 ESTABLISHED
javaw.exe 37044 TCP EL0619 57999 localhost 57998 ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing todo with connections... This just define the number of `EventLoop`s that are used to handle connections. Remember multiple connections can be handled by the same `EventLoop`.

Comment: I understand that 1 EventLoop can handle multiple connections.
While watching TCP Viewer we can see that there are 32 local connections established after instantiating a NioEventLoopGroup when we debug the code prior to assigning to the bootstrap.  Its almost like the EventLoopGroup pre-allocates local connections or something?   Like I said before this is before we do a bind or connect on the bootstrap.    When we release the group, we see these local connections go away.

Comment: NioEventLoopGroup does not open any connections by itself

Comment: I added the local view from TCPViewer for reference.  You can see they are cross connected.  Like I said this occurs at the time you instanciate the NioEventLoopGroup